# Wordpress Custon Post type page not loading

Tags: wordpress

I have created a new post type called "Event" and everything works perfectly. The only thing that is not working is the display of my page-event.php template. It always load the index. Any idea ?

Comment: have you flushed the permalinks?

Comment: nop it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rename page-event.php with `single-event.php`. Hope that helps!